# How to record every allocations and deallocations of memory on a program?

Tags: memory, heap-memory, valgrind, fragmentation

I want to see is fragmentation the reason of increasing memory usage of my twisted server. I have posted a question here:
[How to find the source of increasing memory usage of a twisted server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100192/how-to-find-the-source-of-increasing-memory-usage-of-a-twisted-server)

Now, what I am going to do is to visualize the heap. I found an article: [Memory fragmentation](http://blog.pavlov.net/2007/11/10/memory-fragmentation/). The figure of heap in that article is something just like what I want.  It is not difficult for me to draw such a figure with matplotlib or other tools.  The most difficult job is: how to record the memory allocation and deallocation?

I know that I can modify the source code of CPython, add some logging code into omalloc.c and recompile the Python, and use the modified CPython to run my server. But however, I don't want to waste time with that.  Then I am looking for some available tools.  I know there is a tool **valgrind** can be used to detect memory leak, but I don't know how to record allocation and deallocation.  I see its memcheck can detect something like:

- Invalid read
- Uninitialised
- Invalid free

But that's not what I want, all I need is:

- Record every allocations and deallocations of memory with time, address and size

My questions are:

1. How can I do that with valgrind?
2. If I can't, should I write a module for that?
3. Or is there any better tools can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into Valgrind Massif? http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to question about alternative tools:

I know there there is "Pin" tool, maybe it's worth to check it out: http://www.pintool.org/