# Memory leak while looping web.client.getPage function

Tags: python, memory-leaks, twisted

I have a page what refresh periodically using this script:

```
from twisted.web.client import getPage
from twisted.internet import reactor, task

def getData():
    dgp = getPage('http://www.google.com/')
    dgp.addCallback(dataLoadOK)
    dgp.addErrback(dataLoadError)

def dataLoadOK(value):
    print value

def dataLoadError(error):
    print error

loop = task.LoopingCall(getData)
loop.start(10, now=True)
reactor.run()
```

Buy while using this way I got the memory leak. Has any one help me find there is it?

**Edit:**
I have try to use [garbage collection python module](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/perm.php?a=Python-memory-leak-detector), and got this out put:

```
GARBAGE OBJECTS:
:: <HTTPClientFactory: http://www.google.com/>
        type: <type 'instance'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: <module 'twisted.web.client' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.pyc'>

:: {'status': '200', 'cookies': {'PREF': 'ID=d894e510f2ebe263:FF=0:TM=1306053252:LM=1306053252:S=ebpb4ZebRUu_EhiI', 'NID': '47=LxM9fbBBN-bVIeuLPOfvO-fgXOKw1n2suyZ2...
        type: <type 'dict'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: InsensitiveDict({})
        type: <type 'instance'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: <module 'twisted.python.util' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/util.pyc'>

:: {'preserve': 1, 'data': {}}
        type: <type 'dict'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: <Deferred at 0x29e2cf8 current result: None>
        type: <type 'instance'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: <module 'twisted.internet.defer' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.pyc'>

:: {'_chainedTo': None, 'called': True, '_canceller': None, 'callbacks': [], 'result': None, '_runningCallbacks': False}
        type: <type 'dict'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: <<class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'> to ('www.google.com', 80) at 2445090>
        type: <class 'twisted.internet.tcp.Client'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: <module 'twisted.internet.tcp' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.pyc'>
    line num: 681
        line: class Client(BaseClient):
        line:     """A TCP client."""
        line: 
        line:     def __init__(self, host, port, bindAddress, connector, reactor=None):
        line:         # BaseClient.__init__ is invoked later
        line:         self.connector = connector
        line:         self.addr = (host, port)
        line: 
        line:         whenDone = self.resolveAddress
        line:         err = None
        line:         skt = None
        line: 
        line:         try:
        line:             skt = self.createInternetSocket()
        line:         except socket.error, se:
        line:             err = error.ConnectBindError(se[0], se[1])
        line:             whenDone = None
        line:         if whenDone and bindAddress is not None:
        line:             try:
        line:                 skt.bind(bindAddress)
        line:             except socket.error, se:
        line:                 err = error.ConnectBindError(se[0], se[1])
        line:                 whenDone = None
        line:         self._finishInit(whenDone, skt, err, reactor)
        line: 
        line:     def getHost(self):
        line:         """Returns an IPv4Address.
        line: 
        line:         This indicates the address from which I am connecting.
        line:         """
        line:         return address.IPv4Address('TCP', *(self.socket.getsockname() + ('INET',)))
        line: 
        line:     def getPeer(self):
        line:         """Returns an IPv4Address.
        line: 
        line:         This indicates the address that I am connected to.
        line:         """
        line:         return address.IPv4Address('TCP', *(self.realAddress + ('INET',)))
        line: 
        line:     def __repr__(self):
        line:         s = '<%s to %s at %x>' % (self.__class__, self.addr, unsignedID(self))
        line:         return s

:: {'_tempDataBuffer': [], 'disconnected': 1, 'dataBuffer': '', '_tempDataLen': 0, 'realAddress': ('74.125.225.81', 80), 'connector': <twisted.internet.tcp.Connect...
        type: <type 'dict'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: []
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: {'x-xss-protection': ['1; mode=block'], 'set-cookie': ['PREF=ID=d894e510f2ebe263:FF=0:TM=1306053252:LM=1306053252:S=ebpb4ZebRUu_EhiI; expires=Tue, 21-May-2013 0...
        type: <type 'dict'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: ['-1']
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: ['private, max-age=0']
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: ['text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1']
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: ['PREF=ID=d894e510f2ebe263:FF=0:TM=1306053252:LM=1306053252:S=ebpb4ZebRUu_EhiI; expires=Tue, 21-May-2013 08:34:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com', 'NID=47=LxM9...
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: ['gws']
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: ['1; mode=block']
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: []
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x29e2cb0>
        type: <type 'instance'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: <module 'twisted.internet.tcp' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.pyc'>

:: ['Sun, 22 May 2011 08:34:12 GMT']
        type: <type 'list'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None

:: {'reactor': <twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor object at 0x288bd10>, 'state': 'disconnected', 'factoryStarted': 0, 'bindAddress': None, 'factory': <H...
        type: <type 'dict'>
referrers: 3
    is class: True
    module: None
```

so I saw some unclosed reference inside twisted function, how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some strategies recommended in [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler/110826).  However, it is likely that you don't have a memory leak, you just have [memory fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100192/how-to-find-the-source-of-increasing-memory-usage-of-a-twisted-server).

It looks like the "Python memory leak detector" has a pretty severe bug.  It enables `DEBUG_LEAK` which **prevents all cycles from being collected**.  Put another way, it *creates* lots of massive leaks.  If you just add some code to your example to report the contents of `gc.garbage` without enabling `DEBUG_LEAK`, then it remains empty (`gc.garbage` will be populated if any objects are actually leaking, even if you don't enable any gc debug flags).

Comment: just update my post with result of hunting leaks, the garbage objects are increased each time getData() running

Comment: Updated the answer to talk about a flaw in the "Python memory leak detector".

Answer (score 2):

The way you're scheduling your looping call may be a problem.  You're not returning the `Deferred` from `getData`, so calls may pile up.

If retrieving your web page takes longer than 10 seconds, then it will call the second `getData` before the second `getData` completes.  If you're using a website which attempts to throttle you (and `google.com` definitely does), then the more requests that pile up, the more it will delay you.  Each attempt will take up some memory, which may look like a leak.

If that's the problem (although you should use the techniques that Jean-Paul suggests to discover if that's *actually* the problem), then you can address it by adding "`return dgp`" to the end of your `getData` function.

Comment: Actually in production script, interval is 300 second and more than any timeouts, and I check for prevision `getData()` call complete, this script is simplified for better reading